# Kotlin Spring security + JWT - 401 on registration endpoint

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-security, jwt

I am working on application to learn something more about jwt authentication and I have problem with registration.
I put signup url in antMatchers to permittAll but it does not work. Here is the code:

```
   const val AUTH_LOGIN_URL = "/library/authenticate"
   const val SIGN_UP_URL = "/library/signup"
```

Security Config :

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
    http?.cors()?.and()
            ?.csrf()?.disable()
            ?.authorizeRequests()
            ?.antMatchers(SIGN_UP_URL, AUTH_LOGIN_URL)?.permitAll()
            ?.anyRequest()?.authenticated()
            ?.and()
            ?.exceptionHandling()?.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            ?.and()
            ?.sessionManagement()
            ?.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

    http?.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
}
```

Jwt filter:

```
@Component
class JwtRequestFilter(
        @Autowired
        val jwtTokenProvider: JwtTokenProvider,
        @Autowired
        val customUserDetailsService: CustomUserDetailsService
) : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    override fun doFilterInternal(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, filterChain: FilterChain) {

        var username: String
        var jwtToken = getJwtFromRequrst(request)


        try {
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(jwtToken)) {
                username = jwtTokenProvider.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken)
                val userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username)
                val authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, emptyList())
                authentication.details = WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = authentication
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", e)
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
    }

    private fun getJwtFromRequrst(request: HttpServletRequest): String {
        val bearerToken = request.getHeader(TOKEN_HEADER)
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length)
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

Entry point:

```
@Component
class WebSecurityEntryPoint: AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    override fun commence(request: HttpServletRequest?, response: HttpServletResponse?, authException: AuthenticationException?) {
        response?.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Access denied")
    }
}
```

Using SIGN_UP_URL I always receive 401. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolve issue:

I changed the Controller by adding request mapping:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
class AuthenticationController
```

and then in security config:

```
?.antMatchers("/auth/**")?.permitAll()
```

It starts working.

I think this was the problem:

```
?.antMatchers(SIGN_UP_URL, AUTH_LOGIN_URL)?.permitAll()
```

Maybe if I will declare it one by one it would also work